# MX Linux Not giving me the USB option while trying to install on it

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb, portability

I have make bootable USB of MX Linux with the help of RUFUS software. Now when I am trying to install on USB it does not show me partition to install it while I am booting live setup . The choose the disk installation only show me the hard partition https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewTTX.jpg .While the USB partition is present on the GParted Partition https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHybj.jpg . How can I install MX Linux on USB Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the usb stick is mounted. Difficult to tell from the picture, but doesn't look like it is. Mounting it is as simple as clicking on it's link in the sidebar of your file manager. Or it can also be done with Gparted, under the partition dropdown there is an option that will change depended upon which can be done, either mount or unmount. Make sure you select it first by clicking on it's description, if not the choice will be greyed out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have successfully installed MX Linux on USB drive. I have used two USB. One usb is use for live boot of the MX Linux while the other is used as the partition of installation MX Linux.